# Hyperref font selection problem with babel and french

Tags: fonts, hyperref, babel, forms

How one can change font in the text form?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[bordercolor=white
            ,borderwidth=0
            ,width=2.5in
            ,name=name.1
            ,format={
                var f = this.getField('name.1');
                f.textFont = 'Europe';
                f.userName = 'first name'
            }
            ,value=something
                    ,charsize=7pt]{Type:}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This example is not working. If I open the Adobe Acrobat Pro it says that the forms font is helvetica.
If I change     `\usepackage[english,russian,french]{babel}` to     `\usepackage[english]{babel}` or `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` everything works.

Comment: Do you have this font installed? I tried with other fonts (like Consolas or Times New Roman) it worked.

Comment: Yes, I have this font installed.

Comment: I've updated code, so that it represents the question. I found that the problem with `french` in `babel`.

Comment: Not only french, when I add one more lang to babel this textfont format function not works.

Comment: It works with `\usepackage[english,russian,ukrainian,german]{babel}`. What languages you have tried?

Comment: `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` or `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`

Comment: This two works for me.

Comment: Strange, tried again and it worked, maybe it saved wrongly because `! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option french yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.23 \select@language{french}` when I delete a language and recompile.
And french broke font selection, yes.

Comment: @Ptech The `\select@language` error is normal when you change options for `babel` and will vanish at the next LaTeX run, provided you don't interrupt the present one.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, and I still don't know what to do with french and fontselection in forms.

Comment: For information, I had a problem with babel reporting that a language was not loaded. The trouble was a bad installation of packages. Maybe you may check if your installation is good?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY no, installation is good and french loaded normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `babel` uses shorthand characters for different languages. Example, `;` is redefined as active character if `french` is loaded to insert some space before according to French typography.

With `\shorthandoff` and `\shorthandon` a shorthand character can be dis- and enabled:

```
\shorthandoff{;}%
\TextField...
\shorthandon{;}%
```

Another possibility is the use of `\string` (or e-TeX's `\detokenize`). `\string` converts the next token to a character with catcode "other" (12, such as digits) or "space" (10) if the token has the character code of a space (32).

```
\TextField[...
  format={... f.textFont = 'Europe'\string; ...},
  ....]{...}
```

Another problem is font embedding. The font is only referenced by name and must be installed at the system of the user.

Comment: For me only the `\shorthandoff`/`\shorthandon` way works. Using `pdflatex`.